# What does GCFrame mean in output of !clrstack command in WinDBG?

Tags: asp.net, windbg

Can somebody help me with answering my 2 questions below?

1. What does `GCFrame` mean in !clrStack output?
2. What does `System.IndexOutOfRangeException..ctor()` showing in the stack mean? Does it mean there is actually exception on thread?

```
0:023> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0xe1c (23)
Child SP         IP               Call Site
0000000005cab978 000007fef909caf6 [HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ: 0000000005cab978] System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
0000000005cabb50 000007fef80316ce System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(System.String, System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Version, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
0000000005cabbc0 000007fef8031357 System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
0000000005cabc50 000007fef8038972 System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,System.Resources.ResourceSet>, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
0000000005cabd10 000007fef8038678 System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
0000000005cabdd0 000007fef8038403 System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo, Boolean, Boolean)
0000000005cabe20 000007fef8037fcc System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(System.String, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
0000000005cabec0 000007fef803e10b System.Environment+ResourceHelper.GetResourceStringCode(System.Object)
0000000005cac608 000007fef903ee74 [HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ: 0000000005cac608] System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
0000000005cac730 000007fef803dd88 System.Environment+ResourceHelper.GetResourceString(System.String, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
0000000005cac780 000007fef803e5b8 System.Environment.GetResourceStringLocal(System.String)
0000000005cacb98 000007fef903ee74 [ContextTransitionFrame: 0000000005cacb98] 
0000000005cacb58 000007fef903ee74 [GCFrame: 0000000005cacb58] 
0000000005cacdb8 000007fef903ee74 [HelperMethodFrame_2OBJ: 0000000005cacdb8] System.Environment.GetResourceFromDefault(System.String)
0000000005cacee0 000007fef870fc58 System.IndexOutOfRangeException..ctor()
0000000005cad2c8 000007fef903ee74 [GCFrame: 0000000005cad2c8] 
0000000005cad468 000007fef903ee74 [GCFrame: 0000000005cad468] 
0000000005cad5c0 000007fef903ee74 [GCFrame: 0000000005cad5c0] 
0000000005cad978 000007fef903ee74 [HelperMethodFrame: 0000000005cad978] System.Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(System.Array, Int32, System.Array, Int32, Int32)
0000000005cadab0 000007fef807c705 System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[], Int32, Int32)
0000000005cadb10 000007fef807ba5c System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(System.String)
0000000005cadb70 000007fef807c9ff System.IO.TextWriter+SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(System.String)
0000000005cadbc0 000007ff0021a74e log4net.Util.LogLog.EmitOutLine(System.String)
0000000005cadc10 000007ff00223fdf log4net.Appender.FileAppender.OpenFile(System.String, Boolean)
0000000005cadc90 000007ff00223b31 log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.OpenFile(System.String, Boolean)
0000000005cadd10 000007ff00223837 log4net.Appender.FileAppender.SafeOpenFile(System.String, Boolean)
0000000005cadd70 000007ff005daec3 log4net.Appender.TextWriterAppender.PreAppendCheck()
0000000005caddb0 000007ff005dabc1 log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent)
0000000005cade10 000007ff005da910 log4net.Util.AppenderAttachedImpl.AppendLoopOnAppenders(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent)
0000000005cade90 000007ff005da511 log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.CallAppenders(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent)
0000000005cadf10 000007ff005da12b log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Log(System.Type, log4net.Core.Level, System.Object, System.Exception)
0000000005cadf80 000007ff005de0f2 log4net.Core.LogImpl.DebugFormat(System.String, System.Object[])
0000000005cadff0 000007ff005ddfb0 Secure.Utility.LogHelper.DebugFormat(System.String, System.Object[])
0000000005cae060 000007ff005ded4d Secure.Portal.Messaging.GenericProcessor.OnMessageReceive(WaveSecure.Messaging.GatewayProvider, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, WaveSecure.EventInitiatorTypeList, System.Web.HttpContext)
0000000005cae360 000007ff005dbc3e Secure.Portal.Handlers.XmlServiceMessageHandler.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)
0000000005cae420 000007fef0f1f831 System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
0000000005cae500 000007fef0eec26e System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef)
0000000005cae5d0 000007fef168cff5 System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception)
0000000005cae690 000007fef15b0bf5 System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback)
0000000005cae6e0 000007fef1592576 System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest, System.Web.HttpContext)
0000000005cae780 000007fef167df1f System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)
0000000005cae920 000007fef167e3f2 System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)
0000000005cae970 000007fef167d141 DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int64, Int64, Int32)
0000000005caf228 000007fef90e62e7 [NDirectMethodFrameStandalone: 0000000005caf228] System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)
0000000005caf1f0 000007fef162ff47 DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)
0000000005caf2c0 000007fef167e054 System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)
0000000005caf460 000007fef167e3f2 System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)
0000000005caf4b0 000007fef167d141 DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int64, Int64, Int32)
0000000005caf718 000007fef90e654b [ContextTransitionFrame: 0000000005caf718]
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is in the process of being constructed -- its constructor is currently running. It is probably being thrown by the `BlockCopy` method (you can inspect it in Reflector to see under which conditions it throws this exception). In the process of running the constructor, a satellite resource assembly is being loaded to get a string (which is probably the human-readable exception message).

Comment: Any idea what the `GCFrame` is?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/release/2.2/src/vm/frames.h#L7-L143

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/stackwalking.md

This frame doesn't represent a method call. it's sole purpose is to let the EE gc-protect object references that it is manipulating.